# JVM, JAVA binary and Tomcat..which one provide servlet container?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, solr

I suppose JVM or JAVA is neither providing servlet container and I need some JAVA server like Tomecat to provider container to run servlet which my program (solr) needs it. Even I can start the solr program by issuing java command but it's not really running correctly..

Am I right?

Or what confuses me that on another setup which was successfully done by myself is that I didn't install Tomcat or any kind of Java server and I simply run solr program by issuing java command with parameters and the program keeps running like a daemon and everything just works fine so I assume that the servlet does not need Java server at all.

Please help clear my head up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) container examples include [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).

Solr, just like any Java web app, needs a servlet container to be hosted and run. [The Solr installation docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall) include general and specific information for each container.

When you run `java -jar start.jar` (start.jar comes with the Solr distribution) you're actually running Solr in an [embedded Jetty instance](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Solr_Comes_with_Jetty.2C_is_Jetty_the_recommended_Servlet_Container_to_use_when_running_Solr.3F).